# Consecutive visited days counter does not increment unless page is refreshed

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

I have observed this happening on every browser except for IE. I don't use IE.

I have been continuously visiting a few StackExchange sites for many days now. Every day I feel like going to my profile and checking how many views do my questions have. So when I click on my face in the top bar here, I'm taken to the profile summary page where the visited counter is present. The days visited counter is ok, but the consecutive visits counter shows one day less. For example, if it's my 5th day of visiting, it shows 4. It doesn't show 5 even if I click on it and open a calendar. I have to refresh the page to make it 5. Would someone please take care of this so that it allows me a few more seconds to browse questions on SO and DBA?

Comment: It could be that it's in UTC.

Comment: This sounds like it's by design. *Some* amount of activity is required for the counter to increase

Comment: But why would and activity on a the same page is required to change its contents? I even tried browsing a few questions, voting, answering and then checked my profile page. It was the same.

Comment: Caching, always caching...

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow I understood that reference

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because we load the user *for the page* before we load *you* the user viewing the page.  When we load the user for the page, it has the totals as they were.  When we load *you* (after!) it triggers an update on those daily visit totals if the profile is the first page you visited that counts on that day.  This means the in-memory copy of the user object for the profile remains with old totals.

I hate that behavior and have for years, but never took 5 minutes to fix it.  I just did. The next build will contain this fix.